# Is it okay to ask a question and answer it yourself to share you knowledge?

Tags: support, answers

Pretend I know how to do something that a lot of people can't do or don't know how to, can I do a question like "How can I start a jar file with a batch file?" and answer it? Is that allowed?

P.S. [This topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) is different from mine (At least I think it was unclear.)

Comment: Answered: [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

Comment: @grgarside My question is different from the one you two linked to, look at my edit

Comment: @mgkrebbs Read what told grgarside

Comment: @Coder I see your edit, but besides saying it's different, how exactly *is* it different? From what I understand, it's an exact duplicate. What exactly do you want to know that isn't answered by the linked question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can answer your own questions. It is even [encouraged by Stack Exchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/):

> It’s also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you’re on Jeopardy! — phrase it in the form of a question.
>
> It is OK to ask, and answer, your own question on a relevant Stack Exchange site.
>
> To be crystal clear, **it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged**.

In fact, when you click on the link to ask a question, you will see a checkbox at the bottom giving you the option to answer your own question. Next to the box it says:

> Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style